# Symfony2 not picking up multiple routing yml files / Import not working in yml file

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, symfony-routing

So first off TL:DR - Symfony isn't picking up additional routing files in my bundle. Don't know why. Tried doing imports like in config.yml and it's not working either

I have multiple controllers for maintainability of my code. I.e. All site related actions are in a SiteController, all app related actions are in an AppController, etc.

So I figured I'd make routing files to correspond with my controllers. The files are housed in MyBundle/Resources/config. The thing is they are not being picked up when i do a php app/console router:debug. So I thought, well I'll just import them into the routing_mybundle.yml file that symfony generated during the generate:bundle process. So I did the following:

```
imports:
    - { resource: routing_site.yml }
    - { resource: routing_app.yml }
```

I'm getting an error message that says:

routing_mybundle.yml contains unsupported keys for "import": "0", "1". Expected one of: "resource", "type", "prefix", "pattern", "path", "host", "schemes", "methods", "defaults", "requirements", "options".

I realize that it's looking for specific keys, but I'm not sure why it would work in the config.yml but not in a routing.yml file.

If I do the following it works:

```
imports:
    resource: routing_site.yml
```

Or if I "chain" the imports in the files it works. So by this I mean I import routing_app into routing_site and routing_site into routing_mybundle.

Anyone know how to get the imports tag to work, or how to make it so that symfony will pick up my routing_****.yml files?

Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

Thanks to forgottenbas for the answer. For those who had the same problem as me (multiple config files in the same bundle) here's what I had to do within the routing.yml file **WITHIN** myBundle/Resources/config.

My directory structure looks like

```
MyBundle/
    Resources/
        config/
            routing.yml
            routing_site.yml
            routing_app.yml
```

So I had to do the following

```
SiteController:
    resource: routing_site.yml

AppController:
    resource: routing_app.yml
```

Thanks Again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import routing files this way

**routing.yml**

```
SiteBundle:
    resource: "@SiteBundle/Resources/config/routing_site.yml"

AppBundle:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing_app.yml"
```

[FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-6-import-fosuserbundle-routing-files) do it the same.